# automapper - map properties with values

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two objects, which are basically (so not entirely!) the same. They both have properties with values.

I'd like to map one object to the other and overwrite all the property values of the from the source target to the destination target. But it seems that this isn't happening by default?

**NOTE:**
My maps are already defined at the startup of my application.

My objects basically looks like this:

```
public class Object1
{
    public String Name = "My new Name";
}

public class Object2
{
    public String Name = "My old Name";
}

// Then somewhere in my code:
Mapper.Map(obj1, obj2);
```

So i try to map all the values from `Object1`, to `Object2`. But when the mapping is done, then `Object2` still has its old value, instead of the value from `Object1`.

How can i map the values in AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

`Automapper` returns new instance, assign that return instance to the old one.

```
object1 = Mapper.Map<Object1, Object2>(object2);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that. I'm already defining my maps (otherwise it throws an error). And i'm also mapping instantiated objects, not classes. But the properties that have values (both src and tagret) aren't mapped.

Answer (score 3):

You should configure `AutoMapper` first:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Object1, Object2>();
```

In your example you are trying to map `classes` but its impossible, you should map `instances` of the classes:

```
var o1 = new Object1();
var o2 = new Object2();

Mapper.Map(o1, o2);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that. I'm already defining my maps (otherwise it throws an error). And i'm also mapping instantiated objects, not classes. But the properties that have values (both src and tagret) aren't mapped.